# Why electron apps does not have localStorage object when accesed from development tools? (Ctrl-Shift-I)

Tags: javascript, local-storage, electron

I'm trying to access some data that is presented in discord app  to write it to disc. Because I'm going to do that without human supervision every x seconds, I have thought of using localStorage to store this data, but It seems I can't access this object from the console. I get a localStorage is not defined error. I also tried windows.localStorage without any luck either.

Is there any way to achieve this from a electro app dev console?

Here a picture of the problem:
[image]

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you misspelled it. You should be able to access the localStorage as `window.localStorage` and an item 'X' inside it as, `localStorage.getItem('X')`.

Attaching a screenshot of localStorage accessed in the console.

[image]

Error Scenario screenshot

[image]

Comment: It was an error when writting the question. It is fixed now. But the error is there. I have tried it in a chrome console and it works perfectly. Could be that electron devs stripped it out?

Comment: No, electron browser window does have localStorage support. I am using that in one of my applications.

Comment: Please could you post a screenshot of localStore being used in the electron console? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited my answer with the screenshot.

Comment: Can't understand why it is not working here. The app I want to access is discord. I open discord and press ctrl-shit-I to let the console appear and then try to access localStorage, but it is undefined. Pretty weird!

Comment: Could you please try adding "mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()" this line inside your main.js file of electron app. This line will automatically open the developer tool when the app loads. Then try accessing the localStorage. Just a wild guess though.

Comment: I don't have discord source. It is closed source (The app has not beed developed by me).

Comment: Ohh...then it may have been deleted by the developers of that application. Please see my new screenshot attached.

Comment: Ok, so this can be done by the devers, ok. Thanks for the clarification.