# How to change the browser's localstorage value in an electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to update the localstorage value in main.js file of an electron application. How am I supposed to do so?
When I directly tried to change with below line of code, it's throwing the below error:

```
localStorage.setItem("inMeeting", false);
```

Error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699399/why-electron-apps-does-not-have-localstorage-object-when-accesed-from-developmen

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access localStorage inside main process. The error might be caused by using localStorage in the main process.

Comment: Could you cite some source for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('inMeeting', false);
```

Comment: with above line of code i'm getting as "window" is not defined

Comment: "currentWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('localStorage.setItem("inMeeting", false);', true); " worked for me